# Instantiate a class that derives from MonoBehaviour

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to instantiate a class that derives from MonoBehaviour such as the example bellow without getting the warning: "You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent().  Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all"

Example:

```
public class e1506131012test2 : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Move move = new Move();
    //Move move = gameObject.GetComponent<Move>();

    void Update()
    {
        move.Printing();
    }

}

public class Move : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int number = 5;

    public void Printing()
    {
        print(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what part of "This is not allowed" needs more explanation? Alternatively you can state your actual goal and there could be different approaches to reach it.

Comment: Try : AddComponent(Move); in "class e1506131012test2" and don't let Move derive from MonoBehaviour...

Comment: AddComponent(Move); or gameObject.Addcomponent<Move>(); give me another console error (see the answer bellow). I wish to instantiate a class that derives from MonoBehaviour (eg: class myClass : MonoBehaviour into myOtherClass)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this, the easiest is probably to use [`AddComponent`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) as the error message suggests:

```
Move move;
void Start()
{
    move = gameObject.Addcomponent<Move>();
}
```

The reason you can't just `new` up an object that derives from MonoBehaviour is that such objects must be a component of a `GameObject`. As such, whenever you create one you have to ensure that it is added in a valid way.

Comment: Thank you, when I use

Move move = gameObject.Addcomponent<Move>();

I get an error in the console saying:

"A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `UnityEngine.Component.gameObject"

Hopefully there is a way to instantiate a class derived from MonoBehaviour without getting console errors or warnings. Cheers

Comment: Yeah sorry I wasn't thinking, I've updated my answer to something that should work. Incidentally, if your `e1506131012test2` GameObject is always going to have a `Move` component, you may want to add it via the inspector.

Comment: Thank you Adam, so that means I have to create a new gameObject each time I wish to instantiate a class derived from MonoBehaviour and attach the class scrip to it, right? I wish to keep it on the code level (no drag and drop in the Inspector), would you have a suggestion on what would be the best way to write that? Cheers

Comment: You can't have a MonoBehaviour (component) without a GameObject, but you can have multiple MonoBehaviours (components) attached to a single GameObject. Don't be confused by the use of `gameObject` though, that's a reference to the GameObject that the component is currently a component of.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't derive it from MonoBehaviour.

```
public class Move 
{
    public int number = 5;

    public void Printing()
    {
        print(number);
    }
}
```

And if it really must be a MonoBehaviour, that means you probably have it on a prefab, in which case you use Instantiate().

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your comment.